# C++ program crash in VS2017 Community

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2017

I tried to write simple class. But on the beginning met problem.
When I wrote constructors, 1 destructor and 1 show class method and call it in main function I got unexpected error. The most interesting that during debug mode, in VS2017 Community, error thrown in different places: once in constructor, another in show method, and most of all after return 0 in main function.
That my main.cpp

```
#include "MyScreen.h"

int main()
{
    MyScreen scr = MyScreen(10, 10);
    scr.show();
    char ch;
    std::cin >> ch;
    return 0;
}
```

There is my header file of MyScreen class

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
class MyScreen
{
public:
    MyScreen();
    MyScreen(int, int, char pc = _filler);
    ~MyScreen();

    void show();
private:
    static const int maxHeight;
    static const int maxWidth;
    static const char _filler;
    int _height;
    int _width;
    char *_wContent;
    int _cursor;
};
```

And cpp file

```
#include "MyScreen.h"

const int  MyScreen::maxHeight = 28;
const int  MyScreen::maxWidth  = 118;
const char MyScreen::_filler   = '#';

MyScreen::MyScreen()
{
    _height = maxHeight;
    _width = maxWidth;
    unsigned length = _height * _width;
    _wContent = new char(length);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        _wContent[i] = _filler;
    _cursor = 0;
}

MyScreen::MyScreen(int height, int width, char pc)
{
    _height = height;
    _width = width;
    unsigned length = _height * _width;
    _wContent = new char(length);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        _wContent[i] = pc;
    _cursor = 0;
}

MyScreen::~MyScreen()
{
    delete[] _wContent;
    _wContent = 0;
}

void MyScreen::show()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < _width; j++)
            cout << _wContent[i * 10 + j] << i * 10 + j;
        cout << '\n';
    }
}
```

There are error descriptions that I got:

Critical error detected c0000374
ScreenClass.exe has triggered a breakpoint. (xutility file)

Exception thrown: read access violation.
**ptd** was 0x264FD5EC. (fstream file)

DEBUG ERROR!
HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block(#152) at 0x02ABC5A8.
CTR detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.

I can't understand what I did wrong? I tried to compile and run this code in DevC++ and it throw error too (return 3221226356), but near 3rd recompile of that code it begin work without errors!

Do this problems belong to VS2017? If yes, then how to fix it?

Comment: Should probably be `_wContent = new char[length];`. As is you are allocating space for only one element and subsequently reading out of bounds causing undefined behavior.

Comment: @Ron Should probably be a `std::vector<char>`. FTFY

Comment: @Ron Thanks that solved problem in VS. But why DevC++ accept `new char(length)`?

Comment: @Borgleader Indeed.

Comment: @NemoUA As pointed out in the comments you should prefer the `std::vector<char>` approach as this raw pointer manipulation should be avoided.

Comment: @Ron OK. I noticed it. Thanks for help!

Comment: DevC++ accepts `new char(length)` because it's valid C++. But treating it as an array causes undefined behavior. Appearing to work fine is a valid manifestation of undefined behavior. Trowing an error indicating heap corruption is also a valid manifestation of undefined behavior. Doing anything else is also.

Comment: Additionally, if the compiler declines to elide the copy of the object in `MyScreen scr = MyScreen(10, 10);`, the result is also undefined behavior, because the shown class fails to comply with the Rule Of Three.

Comment: @NemoUA - Although looking very similar, `new char(value);` allocates a single char with an initial value, while `new char[length];` allocates a sequence of bytes.

Comment: @NemoUA, It seems that you have resolved the crashed issue, am I right? If it has been resolved, you could share your solution as an answer, and then mark it. So it could help different community members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
Should be square brackets:

```
_wContent = new char[length];
```

Instead if simple brackets, because () allocates space and initialize only 1 value. But in different IDEs can be different undefined behavior (as in DevC++).
Strongly recommended to use `std::vector<char>` to avoid pointer manipulations that can cause undefined behavior.

Big thx to Ron, Borgleader and Bo Persson for help.